# What gets compressed when you enable dfs.image.compress?

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs

Hadoop [hdfs documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) says this knob specifies whether 'the dfs image' should be compressed.  What exactly does that refer to?  Input files stored in hdfs, output files (there's a separate parameter for that) or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here "dfs image" is a replica of the actual dfs, created while checkpointing. Checkpoints help in reverting to a previous dfs state when the checkpoints were created initially. Image file  consists all the files present in the dfs. Compression would try to compress this file to a smaller size using compression codecs.